# Spring Data JPA findAll() returns empty list from MySQL db

Tags: spring, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I am newbie in Spring.I am trying to get some data from a MYSQL database. Unfortunately spring data jpa returns empty list. But one record exist in db: How can I access this record?

[image: Mysql]
[image: mysql2]

**libraryRepository.java**

```
public interface LibraryRepository extends JpaRepository<Library, String>,LibraryRespositoryCustom{

}
```

**LibraryController.java**

```
@RestController
public class LibraryController {

@Autowired
LibraryRepository repository;

@Autowired
LibraryService libraryService;

@GetMapping("/getAllBooks")
public ResponseEntity<List<Library>> getAllBooks(){
    return ResponseEntity.ok(repository.findAll());
}
```

**application.properties**

```
# Datasource
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/APIDevelopSpringBoot?useSSL=false&serverTimezone=UTC
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=root
#spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

#com.mysql.jdbc.Driver




spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true

# Jpa/Hibernate :
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect

#spring.jpa.database-platform = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update
spring.test.database.replace=none



#Generate Logs
logging.file.name=log/application.log

#spring.profiles.active=dev

spring.main.allow-circular-references: true
```

**Library.java**

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name="LibraryDemo")
public class Library {
    
    @Column(name="book_name")
    private String book_name;
    @Id
    @Column(name="id")
    private String id;
    @Column(name="isbn")
    private String isbn;
    @Column(name="aisle")
    private int aisle;
    @Column(name="author")
    private String author;

}
```

Comment: Double check your table to make sure it really has data.

Comment: Select query gives one record table has data @Tim Biegeleisen

Comment: You have spring.jpa.show-sql=true, so the real query that JPA sends to db must be in the log. Please try to run this query directly in the db, do you see your record there?

Comment: Hibernate: select library0_.id as id1_0_, library0_.aisle as aisle2_0_, library0_.author as author3_0_, library0_.book_name as book_nam4_0_, library0_.isbn as isbn5_0_ from library_demo library0_
Yes, @Vladimir.V.Bvn

Answer (score 1):

```
select library0_.id as id1_0_, library0_.aisle as aisle2_0_, library0_.author as author3_0_, library0_.book_name as book_nam4_0_, library0_.isbn as isbn5_0_ from library_demo library0_
```

As we can see in this query, it is querying on the table library_demo but you have a table named LibraryDemo. So, you have to change the name to library_demo.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have the table name as library_demo for that to work. Whatever name you give, it gets replaced with _ format.

Try this

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "library_demo")
public class Library {...}
```